What can cause "listing a directory" on Android to be 50-250 times slower than expected?
I ended up with my Android device (Google Pixel 7a, on AOSP 15) having accumulated about ~14k videos/photos files in /sdcard/DCIM/Camera. As a consequence I have noticed some very unexpected delay when listing this directory in this particular folder, but also in general.
I do run the following tests
[user@archlinux-box ~] $ ## having the Pixle 7a connected via USB-3 port USB-debugging
[user@archlinux-box ~] $ adb shell
lynx:/ $ ## time the listing of /sdcard/DCIM/Camera
lynx:/ $ (cd /sdcard/DCIM/Camera; time ls | wc)
  13980   13980  398700
    0m04.55s real     0m00.07s user     0m00.31s system
lynx:/ $ ## exclude that it is a fault ot `ls` binary I check via `find` too
lynx:/ $ (cd /sdcard/DCIM/Camera; time find | wc)
  13981   13981  426662
    0m05.25s real     0m00.07s user     0m00.41s system

Being suspicious that listing ~14k files may very well take some time, yet not ~5seconds (and less so upon 2nd time directory listing reads, given I would assume some caching to occur) I tested if this is related to the specific folder /sdcard/DCIM/Camera doing this
lynx:/ $ ## create and enter a test directory to hold 14k files
lynx:/ $ mkdir /sdcard/14k-files-dir
lynx:/ $ cd  /sdcard/14k-files-dir
lynx:/sdcard/14k-files-dir $ ## create 14k files somewhat efficiently
lynx:/sdcard/14k-files-dir $ ## have filenams be comparable length as photo files
lynx:/sdcard/14k-files-dir $ PREFIX='filename-similar-to-photo-files-file-no-'
lynx:/sdcard/14k-files-dir $ seq 1 14000 | sed 's/^/'"$PREFIX"'/' | xargs sh -c 'touch "$@"' _
lynx:/sdcard/14k-files-dir $ ## rerun tests
130|lynx:/sdcard/14k-files-dir $ time ls | wc
  14000   14000  618894
    0m01.92s real     0m00.10s user     0m00.28s system
lynx:/sdcard/14k-files-dir $ time find | wc
  14001   14001  646896
    0m00.72s real     0m00.03s user     0m00.13s system
lynx:/sdcard/14k-files-dir $ time ls | wc
  14000   14000  618894
    0m00.80s real     0m00.10s user     0m00.13s system

as can be seen this time, the directory listing is far faster (particularly once it appears to be in cache).
Lastly I wanted to test - given Android being based on linux kernel - how well my 10+ year laptop would compare.
[user@archlinux-box ~] $ ## running test on a 10 year old laptop
[user@archlinux-box ~] $ mkdir 14k-files-dir
[user@archlinux-box ~] $ cd 14k-files-dir
[user@archlinux-box 14k-files-dir ] $ ## create 14k files somewhat efficiently
[user@archlinux-box 14k-files-dir ] $ ## have filenams be comparable length as photo files
[user@archlinux-box 14k-files-dir ] $ PREFIX='filename-similar-to-photo-files-file-no-'
[user@archlinux-box 14k-files-dir ] $ seq 1 14000 | sed 's/^/'"$PREFIX"'/' | xargs sh -c 'touch "$@"' _
[user@archlinux-box 14k-files-dir ] $ ## run tests on laptop
[user@archlinux-box 14k-files-dir]$ time ls | wc
  14000   14000  632894

real    0m0.025s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.014s
[user@archlinux-box 14k-files-dir]$ time find | wc
  14001   14001  660896

real    0m0.030s
user    0m0.019s
sys     0m0.020s
[user@archlinux-box 14k-files-dir]$ time ls | wc
  14000   14000  632894

real    0m0.021s
user    0m0.009s
sys     0m0.015s


As can be seen the speed listing directories differ vastly. I am puzzled to determine the reasons.

It is mostly unclear why the direct "on Android device" comparison of directories listing times is so huge (1-0.7seconds vs 4-5seconds for /sdcard/DCIM/Camera)
It is puzzling as I would expect both folders residing on the same block-device and filesystem being both below /sdcard ?
In a bigger picture however I cannot wrap my haed around (and seek with this question the causes that a 10 year old linux laptop can list 14k files at 0.02seconds while a rather recent Google Pixel 7a needs 0.7 to 5+ seconds, so plainly 250 times as long?

#Update#
I have found this info on redit which mentions

As mentioned below, it seems on Android 11 ALL file access to external storage goes through SAF, even when targeting API 29 and using standard file access functions. This is a change from Android 10. This explains the difference in speed.

I hence wonder (with regarding to the causes I seek in this question here) if this this still the reason?
Also with this new information I cannot still see why the two folders still have 5-10 times different directory lookup speeds.

This seems to be a known problem of sdcardfs, caused by the case insensitivity of the /sdcard section (to simulate the old sdcards with FAT file-system that were used before Android 4). Google speaks about large folder slowdown from SDCardFS https://source.android.com/docs/core/storage/sdcardfs-deprecate

@Robert no computer/software perfomance pain cannot be made worse knowing that the mad idea of Micorsoft to have file.txt and FiLe.TxT be the same file. yeah I will look into it. I yet almost asume more it at play, because the test files created are still much faster listed as the /sdcard/DCIM/Camera files and I assume it is a sort of overengineered "privacy"/tagging (maybe selinux...) feature there...

@Robert Can you maybe confirm if the path /sdcard on a Google Pixel 7a on a sdcardfs filesystem, how would I dertermine that via adb shell? so I can add the info to the question ?

I don't have a Pixel 7a at hand, on a Pixel4a running Android 13 sdcardfs is used. On a rooted Pixel 8a I only see fuse (don't know if Magsik has an effect on this). I think you have to check it yourself. I use adb and execute mount | grep -i sdcard (no root necessary).

Partial answer
I can't explain all of this, but I can explain parts of it.
Laptop vs /sdcard
That Linux laptop is presumably using ext3 or ext4 filesystems? Those are far more efficient than the simple-minded FAT32 filesystem that Android uses (actually, emulates via sdcardfs) on /sdcard, and operate vastly more quickly.
Why does Android use FAT32?
Android needs to be able to handle storage on exchangeable memory cards (usually micro-SD cards), and those cards need to be readable, writable and formattable on Windows, Linux and macOS. All of those desktop/laptop operating systems can handle FAT32, but getting them to handle each other's main filesystems is much harder.
Android also has the capability to "adopt" a memory card as part of the device's storage, and that's far simpler if the device's storage uses the same kind of filesystem as a memory card.
For extra complexity, Android's native internal filesystem is ext4 but it uses a FUSE ("Filesystem in Userspace") driver to let the internal storage be accessed as FAT32.
Why is listing 14,000 zero-byte files faster than 14,000 photos?
That's the part I don't know, but the obvious experiment is to create 14,000 files, each about the same size as your typical photos, and see if that's as slow as the photos. I expect it will be.

Android (since 4?) does not use but simulate a FAT32 case insensitive file-system using sdcardfs.

@Robert: Thanks, added.

the pixel 7a (as mentioned) does not support mmc/sdcards. I guess the naming of the directory /sdcard (which often is /storage/emulated/0) appears to be some naming form the past, when it was usual that sd-cards played a role. I guess we can rule out FAT32 playing a role in modern android devices like Google Pixel 7a :)
